# undefined добавляется к массиву

Tags: javascript

Когда вывожу элементы подмассива в ячейки таблицы через цикл `for`, то первым выводится `undefined`, а потом уже все элементы: `undefined Hello world   Phrase  23  qwerty  lorem`

Сам код:

```js
var arr = [
  ["Hello", "world", "Phrase", "23", "qwerty", "lorem"],
  ["56", "wetrf", "random", "099", "world", "Phrase"],
  ["23", "qwerty", "lorem", "56", "wetrf", "random"],
  ["Hello", "wew", "Phrase", "23", "qwerty", "lorem"],
  ["Bye", "world", "Element", "23", "qwerty", "lorem"]
];
var table = document.getElementById('tab')
var i = 0;

function button() {
  var el = document.createElement('tr');
  table.appendChild(el);
  var row;
  for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    row += '<td>' + arr[i][j] + '</td>';
  }

  el.innerHTML = row;

}
```

```html
<table id="tab"> </table>
<input type="button" value="Кнопка" onclick="button()">
```

Из-за чего это может быть? Как сделать так, чтобы выводились только элементы, содержащиеся в подмассиве?

Comment: Можно конечно вам ответить на вопрос, но (!!!), считаю логичнее напомнить (или открыть секрет), что в браузере есть инструменты разработчика и в частности такая волшебная штука, как отладчик (debugger). И вы можете воспользоваться им и по шагам пройти все итерации и посмотреть какая переменная на каком этапе какое значение принимает. И тогда не придется на каждый чих создавать вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема банальна.

Вы пишете:

```
var row;
```

Тут, в переменную записывается `undefined`, т.к. по дефолту не присвоено значение, и уже дальше к нему (к значению undefined) вы конкатенируете данные из цикла.

Решение: объявить переменную, как полагается, с ожидаемым типом:

```
var row = '';
```

**P.S.** Повторю свои слова из комментария:

Считаю, что нужно вам напомнить (или открыть секрет), что в браузере есть инструменты разработчика, и в частности такая волшебная штука, как отладчик (debugger). И вы можете воспользоваться им, и по шагам пройти все итерации и посмотреть какая переменная на каком этапе какое значение принимает. И тогда не придется на каждый чих создавать вопрос. Советую почитать что-то на эту тему и отлаживать свой код. Как пример: https://learn.javascript.ru/debugging-chrome

Comment: Если бы нубы умели слушать, SO не было бы. Так что...

Comment: @vp_arth Спасибо. Кажется я тупею...